# Embeded HTML- responsive css

Tags: html, css

A realtor site is allowing my friend to embed html into her site page, which is built off a drag and drop template. I know html and responsive css. However I can't seem to figure how to use embedded html with responsive css? I want to embed a image.

Can I use external css with embedded html? Seeing I can't seem to state head tags, I don't think this is possible. Would inline be a option? Would style tag work with embeded html?

Comment: Why not use i frame instead

Comment: the iframe would need to be responsive, so i would run into the same problem with where to put the css. I am trying to embed a image in html, which needs to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<iframe height="100" width="100 title="Iframe title" src="" loading="eager" name="iframe" id="iframe1">
</iframe>
```

in your css:

```
#iframe1 {
your css here...
}
```